how to update two table data in single form in php
public function updatetheater(Request $req,$id){
$update=DB::table('theater')->where('id',$id)->first();                  $update_email=DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->first();
return view('updatetheater',compact('update','update_email'));
}
Public function displaytheater(Request $req,$id){

    $update_userId = DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->update([
        'email' => $req->input('Mail')
        
    ]);
    DB::table('theater')->update->where('id',$id)->update([
        'theater_name' => $req->input('Theater_name'),
        'location' => $req->input('Location'),
        'login-id' => $update_userId 
    ]);

return redirect()->back()->with('update','Theater Update Successfully');
}
 $update->id])}}">
      
        @csrf
      
            theater_name}}">
            location}}">
            login-id}}">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark"name="btn" value="Update">

  </form>

i had try to update email with theater  update form.i dont know.....i have already add email-id from 'users' table to my 'theater' table using insertGetID method.
Now I want to update my email using update theater ......

Please edit your question so the code is formatted as a code block. Even when I add the code block fences the line breaks are wrong.
